# Exported Liferay 6.2 LAR file size not match when download

Tags: liferay

Im having issue to download Liferay LAR file. When I try to download the exported LAR, found that the size is not match with the one stated in description. The size should be 33.4GB but browser detected as 1.47GB only. I've tried with Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it is a download problem due to timeout? It's very strange...

By the way, if I'm not in wrong, LAR generated files are stored in a temporary folder... so you can try to search for it.

Just a question: if you are able to get the LAR, are you sure you will be able to upload a so large file in Liferay for importing?

Comment: It not even start to download.. in firefox, when you click download in any page, will popup where to store your file right? there will show you the file size. It not matching. I can't share the screenshot here, i don't have enough badges.

Btw, I found the generated file in tmp folder but in <some-id>.zip. The size is match, but not sure this is the LAR file.

Comment: LARs are ZIP files... I think you found the right file: if it's not corrupt (try to unpack) you can rename it as .LAR... but my last question remains: now are you able to upload a so large file?

Comment: Im not so sure about that actually, but our plan is to merge our Document Library and Media into one from other installation. That why it so large.  I did not see there is a limitation to upload a large file from Liferay export/import guide. Hopefully Im not missed any information about importing a large file to Liferay?

Comment: No, I think there isn't not official limitation about... mine was just a question, because you're having problem with download also (and I don't know if it a good idea to work with so huge files in LR). In my mind (I don't know if it's possible in you situation) trying to export files and preferences in different LARs (e.g. one for document, one for articles, one for pages etc.) can be a better idea to avoid using so large files.